# RoleManager crashes application asp.net MVC WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, roles

my RoleManager keeps failing to connect to the database
my application's roles work fine in my ASP.net MVC webApi application without it, but i can't get the roles of a user without adding RoleManager to the WebConfig

this is a part of the webconfig containing the RoleManager definition

```
<system.web>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="newprovider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="On">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="Forbidden.aspx" />
</customErrors>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

and this is the code I have in my RolesController

```
[Authorize]
public class RolesController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Roles
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        string[] roleNames = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
        return roleNames;
    }
}
```

when i have the RoleManager part in the WebConfig my application doesn't even show the index page, it shows an error:

Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

EDIT: now shows error on Line 20:              type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"

Comment: Couldn't load the error page?

Comment: it shows this
Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Comment: That means something in your error handling logic is failing.

Comment: well how can i handle the error if i can't even see what the error is and why/where it occurs?
the only thing i know about it is that it only occurs when i add the RoleManager to the webConfig

Comment: Turn off custom errors, that may help you to see real error. And then figure out what's going on in your error handling that's causing errors.

Comment: Your error handling logic should be defensively coded - design it in such a way that it can't cause a new exception to be thrown.

Comment: done that, it now saysLine 20:              type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"